# (webpack 4) + sass-loader + mini-css-extract-plugin , ignore sass dependencies, generated css is missing in the output dir

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I've added an issue in github ( but yet I'm not sure which plugin this problem belong )  but maybe someone have found a workaround/different approach for this

I've also created a sample project so you can play&try in 1 minute

the problem seems that from the javascript entrypoint the import load correctly css files and sass files, but the sass files, once converted doesn't get placed in output dir ( by mini-css-extract-plugin ) while the css does..

(also note that extract-text plugin seems doesn't have this problem )

the readme of the sample-project also contain more detailed instruction on how to run it and output
https://github.com/fvigotti/webpack-problem-scss

I don't want to add all my sass as entrypoint ( this solution seems to work but this is not the way it should work and it's also a code smell because then I have to mantain dependencies between entrypoints and styles in the webpack configuration.. )

someone have a solution or a working example ?

thank you,
Francesco

Comment: have you tried extract-text-plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin And this issue https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/14 ?

Comment: extract-text-webpack-plugin  is incompatible with webpack4  , the web says to use  MiniCssExtractPlugin , About the issue you've pointed to , I've created a branch, but this doesn't work either.. https://github.com/fvigotti/webpack-problem-scss/tree/example-singleModuleRule

Comment: There are workaround regarding extract-text-webpack-plugin use `npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next` and verify yourself once again if its at least v4.0.0-alpha.0 It should work.

Comment: extract-text-webpack-plugin works fine with webpack 4.Check this github repo contains sample project of webpack 4 and sass https://github.com/Rajcbe/Webpack-sample-project

Comment: @Raj the repo you pointed to isn't webpack4 but webpack3

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem,
In package.json ( which I've inherited from another project ) 
this :

`"sideEffects": [
    "*.css"
  ],`

caused this issue,
I don't know why if affected the only the scss and not the css,  even when they are bot handled by same module ( and same rule ) only the css ( maybe is a bug, but minor in this case )  is exported and not the sass , anyway removing this from my sample project , now works :)
I'll add a commit to my project with a working version so it can still be referenced as working example